# Java project is not running on tomcat server from tomcat manager after deploying war file to webapps?

Tags: java, spring-boot, ubuntu, tomcat, war

I have made a project on spring tool suit. This project is running fine in local embaded tomcat server. But when I deployed the war file to the external tomcat servers webapps folder I cannot run the project from the tomcat manager. **When I click start it shows two errors: FAIL - Application at context path [/payemntmodule] could not be started
FAIL - Encountered exception [org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/paymentmodule]]]**

Here are the details of my project:

**java version**

```
java --version
openjdk 11.0.11 2021-04-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2.20.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.11+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2.20.04, mixed mode, sharing)
```

**tomcat.service**

```
[Service]
Type=forking

Environment=JAVA_HOME= /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64
Environment=CATALINA_PID=/opt/tomcat/temp/tomcat.pid
Environment=CATALINA_HOME=/opt/tomcat
Environment=CATALINA_BASE=/opt/tomcat
Environment=CATALINA_OPTS=-Xms512M -Xmx1024M -server -XX:+UseParallelGC
Environment=JAVA_OPTS= -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom

ExecStart=/opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh
ExecStop=/opt/tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh

User=tomcat
Group=tomcat
UMask=0007
RestartSec=10
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

[![/opt/tomcat/webapps][1]][1]

[![Deployed war file to the tomcat manager][2]][2]

[![File permissions of webapps][3]][3]

**Errors:**

```
FAIL - Application at context path [/paymentmodule] could not be started
FAIL - Encountered exception [org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start 
component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/paymentmodule]]]
```

[![Tomcat Manager with error][4]][4]

**Logs:**

[![tomcat.log][5]][5]

**manager.log**

[![manager.log][6]][6]

[![manager.log][7]][7]

[![manager.log][8]][8]

Comment: The details of the error can be found in the log files, please add them to your question.

Comment: Can you please tell me how can I check the log files in the tomcat server? @PiotrP.Karwasz

Comment: The logs are in the `/opt/tomcat/logs` directory. A deployment error should be in `localhost.<date>.log`, but check also `catalina.<date>.log` and `manager.<date>.log`.

Comment: I have added the logs in my question. Can you please help me by looking at the logs? @PiotrP.Karwasz

Comment: Please don't add logs and other text information as images! Add them as text (copy/paste). The images you posted lack cut the end of the error messages (the real cause is at the end) and are not searchable.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your app does not knows that it is invoked by external tomcat.
Need to change scope to provided,add this in pom and check

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>  
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>  
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I added this to my pom.xml file while generating the .war file.